# size of String variable in bytes

Tags: javascript, string, size

I have a large String variable and I want to check how big this variable is.
It's in Javascript.

```
var data_url = "testestestetestete....................."
```

How can I determine the size of `data_url` in bytes?

Comment: .length gets me stringlength, i want it in bytes

Comment: .length on a string gets me the amount of characters in this string. I want to know how many bytes this String needs in memory

Comment: The answers in the duplicate are outdated, nowadays you're simply using Blobs: `len = new Blob([data_url]).size`.

Comment: thanks, that is what i was looking for!